# git push heroku master fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I'm on Mountain Lion. My username is admin.

***UPDATE!!! After running the next three lines in terminal - all is well!***

```
export ARCHFLAGS='-arch x86_64'
export PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin:${PATH}
gem install pg
```

When I try to do git push heroku master. It fails. I'm having so much trouble. I'm not sure what to do.

**'which heroku'** results in **/usr/bin/heroku**

**which git** results in **/usr/local/git/bin/git**

**ruby -v** results in **ruby 1.8.7**

Im running Postgres version 1.0 (11)

**I have a Gemfile and a Gemfile.lock:**

```
new-host:testing3 admin$ ls -la
total 72
drwxr-xr-x  21 admin  staff   714 Dec  9 18:40 .
drwx------+  6 admin  staff   204 Dec  8 16:20 ..
drwxr-xr-x  14 admin  staff   476 Dec 10 00:59 .git
-rw-r--r--   1 admin  staff   609 Dec  9 20:12 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--   1 admin  staff   812 Dec  9 20:14 Gemfile
-rw-r--r--   1 admin  staff  2502 Dec  6 17:54 Gemfile.lock
-rw-r--r--   1 admin  staff   204 Dec  9 18:40 README.markdown
-rw-r--r--   1 admin  staff  9208 Dec  6 17:54 README.rdoc
-rw-r--r--   1 admin  staff   273 Dec  6 17:54 Rakefile
drwxr-xr-x   8 admin  staff   272 Dec  8 18:28 app
drwxr-xr-x  10 admin  staff   340 Dec  6 17:54 config
-rw-r--r--   1 admin  staff   158 Dec  6 17:54 config.ru
drwxr-xr-x   4 admin  staff   136 Dec  8 16:34 db
drwxr-xr-x   3 admin  staff   102 Dec  6 17:54 doc
drwxr-xr-x   4 admin  staff   136 Dec  6 17:54 lib
drwxr-xr-x   4 admin  staff   136 Dec  8 16:33 log
drwxr-xr-x   8 admin  staff   272 Dec  6 17:54 public
drwxr-xr-x   3 admin  staff   102 Dec  6 17:54 script
drwxr-xr-x   8 admin  staff   272 Dec  6 17:54 test
drwxr-xr-x   6 admin  staff   204 Dec  8 16:33 tmp
drwxr-xr-x   4 admin  staff   136 Dec  6 17:54 vendor
```

**Gemfile.lock looks like this:**

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.9)
      actionpack (= 3.2.9)
      mail (~> 2.4.4)
    actionpack (3.2.9)
      activemodel (= 3.2.9)
      activesupport (= 3.2.9)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.4.0)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.2.1)
    activemodel (3.2.9)
      activesupport (= 3.2.9)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.9)
      activemodel (= 3.2.9)
      activesupport (= 3.2.9)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.9)
      activemodel (= 3.2.9)
      activesupport (= 3.2.9)
    activesupport (3.2.9)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    arel (3.0.2)
    builder (3.0.4)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.4.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (1.4.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    hike (1.2.1)
    i18n (0.6.1)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-rails (2.1.4)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.7.5)
    mail (2.4.4)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.19)
    multi_json (1.4.0)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.4.1)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-ssl (1.3.2)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.9)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.9)
      actionpack (= 3.2.9)
      activerecord (= 3.2.9)
      activeresource (= 3.2.9)
      activesupport (= 3.2.9)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.9)
    railties (3.2.9)
      actionpack (= 3.2.9)
      activesupport (= 3.2.9)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (>= 0.14.6, < 2.0)
    rake (10.0.2)
    rdoc (3.12)
      json (~> 1.4)
    sass (3.2.3)
    sass-rails (3.2.5)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    sprockets (2.2.2)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.6)
    thor (0.16.0)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    treetop (1.4.12)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.35)
    uglifier (1.3.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1)
  jquery-rails
  rails (= 3.2.9)
  sass-rails (~> 3.2.3)
  sqlite3
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
```

**Gemfile looks like this:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.9'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

#gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.2.5', :group => development

gem 'pg'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

**I did the following to get my repository on github to be pushed to my subdomain on heroku (which I made by doing 'heroku create' in iterm), but it failed:**

```
new-host:testing3 admin$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 72, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (58/58), done.
Writing objects: 100% (72/72), 26.90 KiB, done.
Total 72 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.2.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs bin/ --deployment
       You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
       your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
       updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
       You have added to the Gemfile:
       * pg
       You have deleted from the Gemfile:
       * sqlite3
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

To git@heroku.com:limitless-thicket-9719.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:limitless-thicket-9719.git'
new-host:testing3 admin$
```

**I did the following, because I installed postgres so that it is in my Applications folder and is named Postgres.app:**

```
new-host:testing3 admin$ gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_config
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_config
Using config values from /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
    --with-pg-config
    --with-pqlib
    --without-pqlib
    --with-libpqlib
    --without-libpqlib
    --with-ms/libpqlib
    --without-ms/libpqlib


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/pg-0.14.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/pg-0.14.1/ext/gem_make.out
new-host:testing3 admin$ --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
-bash: --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory
new-host:testing3 admin$ --with-pg
-bash: --with-pg: command not found
new-host:testing3 admin$ --without-pg
-bash: --without-pg: command not found
new-host:testing3 admin$ --with-pg-dir
-bash: --with-pg-dir: command not found
new-host:testing3 admin$ --without-pg-dir
-bash: --without-pg-dir: command not found
new-host:testing3 admin$ --with-pg-include
-bash: --with-pg-include: command not found
new-host:testing3 admin$ --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
-bash: --without-pg-include=dir/include: No such file or directory
new-host:testing3 admin$ --with-pg-lib
-bash: --with-pg-lib: command not found
new-host:testing3 admin$ --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
-bash: --without-pg-lib=dir/lib: No such file or directory
new-host:testing3 admin$ --with-pg-config
-bash: --with-pg-config: command not found
new-host:testing3 admin$ --with-pqlib
-bash: --with-pqlib: command not found
new-host:testing3 admin$ --without-pqlib
-bash: --without-pqlib: command not found
new-host:testing3 admin$ --with-libpqlib
-bash: --with-libpqlib: command not found
new-host:testing3 admin$ --without-libpqlib
-bash: --without-libpqlib: command not found
new-host:testing3 admin$ --with-ms/libpqlib
-bash: --with-ms/libpqlib: No such file or directory
new-host:testing3 admin$ --without-ms/libpqlib
-bash: --without-ms/libpqlib: No such file or directory
new-host:testing3 admin$ 
new-host:testing3 admin$ 
new-host:testing3 admin$ Gem files will remain installed in /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/pg-0.14.1 for inspection.
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
    Unknown command files
new-host:testing3 admin$ Results logged to /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/pg-0.14.1/ext/gem_make.out
```

**When I do this:**

```
new-host:testing3 admin$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Using rake (10.0.2) 
Using i18n (0.6.1) 
Using multi_json (1.4.0) 
Using activesupport (3.2.9) 
Using builder (3.0.4) 
Using activemodel (3.2.9) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.4) 
Using rack (1.4.1) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.2.2) 
Using actionpack (3.2.9) 
Using mime-types (1.19) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.12) 
Using mail (2.4.4) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.9) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.35) 
Using activerecord (3.2.9) 
Using activeresource (3.2.9) 
Using bundler (1.2.3) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.4.0) 
Using execjs (1.4.0) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
Using json (1.7.5) 
Using rdoc (3.12) 
Using thor (0.16.0) 
Using railties (3.2.9) 
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2) 
Using jquery-rails (2.1.4) 
Installing pg (0.14.1) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pqlib
    --without-pqlib
    --with-libpqlib
    --without-libpqlib
    --with-ms/libpqlib
    --without-ms/libpqlib


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/pg-0.14.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/pg-0.14.1/ext/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing pg (0.14.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.14.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export ARCHFLAGS='-arch x86_64'
export PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin:${PATH}
gem install pg
```

Go to Gemfile in your project folder, open it up in your editor and make it look like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.9'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

#gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.2.5', :group => development

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

#group :development, :test do
#  gem 'sqlite3'
#end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

save the file

run bundle install --without production

git add .

git commit -a -m "Heroku recommit"

git push

git push heroku master

Comment: also if you're trying to access a controller and you're getting a "We're sorry but something went wrong" message then do this: heroku run rake db:migrate

Comment: also when you create your heroku instance make sure you do: "heroku create --stack cedar"

Comment: so if you're trying to push your local database to heroku, you need to install the taps gem, but don't use sudo. So do this: "gem install taps". More coming soon.

Answer (score 2):

What is happening is that you're trying to push to the live server when your local gems are not properly configured based on changes you've made to your Gemfile.

The last error message suggestion, making sure that `gem install pg` works is a good one. First, you should probably totally uninstall Postgres. Then, install Postgres.app from http://postgresapp.com -- this is the easiest way to get it running.

Once that's installed and you can properly connect to it using command line tools, try running `gem install pg` and see if that works. If it does, run `bundle install` and it should complete successfully. Once that's working, you should be able to push to heroku without problems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tim. postresapp.com is where I downloaded postgress in the first place. I guess I'll try installing it using homebrew instead and try it again.

Comment: I uninstalled postgres and reinstalled it using homebrew and tried gem install pg, and it gave me the same error :(. 

Any ideas?